# Debian: create a new user without home directory

Tags: debian, users, debian-lenny

How do I create a new user in Debian without home directory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not really sure if you can create a user which doesn't have a home directory specified. That being said, the specified home directory doesn't have to exists. You can call the *adduser* with the option *--no-create-home*.

adduser --no-create-home foo

(adduser is usually the preferred higher level tool if called interactively.)

Answer (score 2):

According to the man page of `useradd(8)` you either want to add the parameter `-M` to your `useradd` call or you want to set `CREATE_HOME=no` in `/etc/default/useradd`.

> ```
> -M
> Do no create the user's home directory,
> even if the system wide setting from
> /etc/login.defs (CREATE_HOME) is set to yes.
> ```

Comment: -1, the very first paragraph of useradd(8) tells you, not to use it, but adduser.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian based systems typically the [`adduser`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=adduser&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+5.0+lenny&format=html&locale=en) command is used to create new accounts instead of directly calling `useradd`.

The `adduser` option to skip creating a home directory is `--no-create-home`.

Answer (score 1):

$ useradd joe
    $useradd -m joe does the opposite

edit : 
rtfm ;)
http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd

Comment: does the opposite? doesnt it just "make" the user?

Comment: useradd -m creates the home dir (for instance /home/joe)

Comment: Depending on the settings for `$CREATE_HOME` in `/etc/default/useradd` the second command certainly does not do the opposite…

Comment: ain't you confusing -m and -M (in capitals) ?

-m, --create-home
The user's home directory will be created if it does not exist. The files contained in SKEL_DIR will be copied to the home directory if the -k option is used, otherwise the files contained in /etc/skel will be used instead. Any directories contained in SKEL_DIR or /etc/skel will be created in the user's home directory as well. The -k option is only valid in conjunction with the -m option. The default is to not create the directory and to not copy any files.

Comment: please stop down-rate without any explanation. thanks

Comment: -1, the very first paragraph of useradd(8) tells you, not to use it, but adduser.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the original question... my bad

Answer (score -1):

As root on a Linux machine

```
[root@stapp01 ~]# cat /etc/passwd | grep anita
[root@stapp01 ~]# useradd -M anita
[root@stapp01 ~]# id anita
uid=1002(anita) gid=1002(anita) groups=1002(anita)
[root@stapp01 ~]# cat /etc/passwd | grep anita
anita:x:1002:1002::/home/anita:/bin/bash
[root@stapp01 ~]#
[root@stapp01 ~]# ll /home/
total 8
drwx------ 2 ansible ansible 4096 Oct 15  2019 ansible
drwx------ 2 tony    tony    4096 Jan 25  2020 tony
[root@stapp01 ~]#
```

Parameter of command `useradd`:

```
-M
The user home directory will not be created, even if the system wide settings from /etc/login.defs is to create home dirs.
```